# Using filters in linq expression tree

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My idea is that I expose an `api` controller `​/api​/Events​/{clientId}​/{projectId}/{eventTypeId}`
these tree parameters will be acting like filters in querying my `db.Events` table.
If I pass `ClientId`, and not pass other two filters it should just do filtering by `ClientId`.

I tried with this method:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> Handle(GetEventsByClientIdAndProjectIdQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Expression<Func<Event, int?>> clientId = (s => query.ClientId);
    Expression<Func<Event, int?>> projectId = (s => query.ProjectId);
    Expression<Func<Event, int?>> eventTypeId = (s => query.EventTypeId);

    if (query.ProjectId.HasValue)
    {
        projectId = (p => p.ProjectId.Equals(query.ClientId)); //error: cannot implicitly convert type bool to int?
    }

    if (query.EventTypeId.HasValue)
    {
        eventTypeId = (e => e.EventTypeId == query.EventTypeId.Value);
    }

    var evts = await _context.Events.Where(clientId) //error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<UNW.Domain.Entities.Event, int?>>' to 'System.Func<UNW.Domain.Entities.Event, bool>'
                                    .Where(projectId)
                                    .Where(eventTypeId)
                                    .ToListAsync();
                
                

    if (evts == null)
        return null;

    return evts.AsReadOnly();
}
```

and my `GetEventsByClientIdAndProjectIdQuery` model:

```
public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
public int? ClientId { get; set; }
public int? EventTypeId { get; set; }
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You can made it simpler

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> Handle(GetEventsByClientIdAndProjectIdQuery query, 
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var dbQuery = _context.Events;
    if (query.ProjectId.HasValue)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(p => p.ProjectId.Equals(query.ClientId));
    }
    if (query.EventTypeId.HasValue)
    {
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(e => e.EventTypeId == query.EventTypeId.Value);
    }
    //same goes for projectID which is missing from your question

    var evts = await dbQuery.ToListAsync();
                
    //evts will nerver be null, you might want do something for evts.Count==0
    //but it is fine to return an empty list

    return evts.AsReadOnly();
}
```

Comment: You can remove check for null. ToListAsync never returns null.

Answer (score 1):

The most concise solution I can think of

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<Event>> Handle(GetEventsByClientIdAndProjectIdQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  => await _context.Events
        .Where(evt => evt.ClientId.Equals(query.ClientId))
        .Where(evt => query.ProjectId.HasValue ? evt.ProjectId.Equals(query.ProjectId.Value) : true)
        .Where(evt => query.EventTypeId.HasValue ? evt.EventTypeId.Equals(query.EventTypeId.Value) : true)
        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken)
        .AsReadOnly();
```

**If** the filter is provided
**Then** use it
**Otherwise** do not filter out the element

Answer (score 0):

I like and am a fan of the simplicity of @Magnetron's answer, but to build off of your existing code:

```
//error: cannot implicitly convert type bool to int?
```

Issue 1: The signatures for `clientId`, `projectId` and `eventTypeId` are all set up to return a nullable int (Func<Event, int?), but `.Equals()` returns a boolean value.

Assuming I'm understanding what you want to accomplish, you can try the below updates:

```
// 1. Change the return values from int? to boolean.
// 2. Go ahead and set your expression to return Events where the ClientId is equal
//    to the ClientId passed in with your query parameter
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> clientId = 
                                 (s => s.ClientId.Equals(query.ClientId));

// 3. Similar to the above with ClientId, but we also include the guard clauses for the optional parameters (ProjectId and EventTypeId)
      
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> projectId = 
                                 (s => (!query.ProjectId.HasValue || query.ProjectId == 0) || s.ID.Equals(query.ProjectId));
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> eventTypeId = 
                                 (s => (!query.EventTypeId.HasValue || query.EventTypeId == 0) || s.ID.Equals(query.EventTypeId));

// (Issue 2 with clientId resolved by the updates made to resolve Issue 1)
var evts = await _context.Events.Where(clientId) 
                                .Where(projectId)
                                .Where(eventTypeId)
                                .ToListAsync();
            
            
if (evts == null)
    return null;

return evts.AsReadOnly();
```